# No bootmanager splash screen and can't get into BIOS

Tags: bios

I have a Toshiba satellite laptop on which Windows Vista and Linux Mint (Sarah) are installed on.

Originally I could dual boot into either system I needed: when my computer started I could get into my BIOS the usual way by pressing F2 (Toshiba's suggested method).

Here is my problem: now when I boot the computer loads directly into Linux and entirely bypasses the boot manager or grub ( not sure the proper term ). Also at start up I am no longer able to enter BIOS by way of F2. I have run boot repair and may have made changes inadvertently that caused my problem.

I think but am not sure that somehow my system is not looking at ( or overlooking) the partition that Vista is located on. I know it is still there from reports I have run. I have researched this issue and read the help pages but I think my ignorance on the subject has caused this problem.

What I want to do is get back the ability to boot from either system and access the BIOS settings again.

My boot repair utility report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26140627/

Comment: Try shutting down the system. Then press F2 while the power is actually off. Than push power button while pressing F2 at same time. And you should boot in bios. See if this helps.

Comment: Tried that as well with no success.

Answer (score 0):

On a terminal emulator like gnome terminal, run as root `grub-install /dev/sda`. If any errors happen while installing check [grub archwiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub) for info how to solve in. Afterwards run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. If after reboot Windows disappeared from grub then run `os-prober` and `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` again.

Answer (score 0):

Press Esc button continuously as soon as  you power on your pc,  it will take you to bios menu.

Comment: Escape button as well as the other usual function keys (F1-F12 ) shift key but none allow me to get to Bios settings. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Thank you all who have offered possible fixes for my problem but I still am not able to access my bios settings and can only boot to Linux mint (originally I could choose between Vista and). Someone sent me a link to some info about Linux kernels and bios corruption.I am not the only one having problems I see.
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?pa...BIOS-Corrupter
Also this was noted:
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop